# Clicks on OpenGraph links in timeline fail to authenticate with "Error validating verification code"

Tags: oauth, facebook-opengraph, facebook-authentication, facebook-oauth, facebook-timeline

I'm trying to authenticate users coming to my site from a click on an opengraph action in facebook.

I've generate the action successfully with the following code.  This
goes out to my timeline successfully.  So far, so good.

```
require 'cgi'

client_id ="CLIENT_ID"
client_secret = "CLIENT_SECRET"

recipe = "http://foodonthetable.shadr.us/recipes/1007-spanish-chicken-and-rice"
access_token = "LONGACCESSTOKEN"

# PUBLISH
result = `curl -F access_token=#{access_token} -F recipe=#{recipe} https://graph.facebook.com/me/foodonthetable_mrh:plan_to_cook`
puts result
```

When I click on the link in the timeline, I'm taken to the following URL.  This is where
I start having issues.  Basically, I want to recognize the user coming in
through this link and log them in (or create a new user).  I have
authenticated referrals turned on, and I'm receiving the `code` parameter as
expected.

```
http://foodonthetable.shadr.us/recipes/1007-spanish-chicken-and-rice?fb_action_ids=384156608318085&fb_action_types=foodonthetable_mrh%3Aplan_to_cook&fb_source=timeline_og&action_object_map=%7B%22384156608318085%22%3A10151004406923956%7D&code=AQAPExNw7MHkxcLTEi5L24iD79pVa-WYxyhBA_bhdWLCM0PCGDuPjh1WqmAyd3_O3_LSjYzPawrinHNP3nv9BCMB_XuTnr8De8xQ2AwXqCaeHUzZUPm2MPyQ_eodOC9-YtjkvXm_PzRX3JG58khalT3AJjVuZvKHn5hWGDSohXLRbHGxW-vOg_Whm3mt_WUkdd0#_=_
```

However, when I try to get the `auth_token` using this code, I'm not able to.
I've tried using a couple of different versions of the `redirect_uri` thinking
that might be the problem (based on other posts) but nothing seems to work.

```
redirect_uri = "http://foodonthetable.shadr.us/recipes/1007-spanish-chicken-and-rice"
redirect_uri = "http://foodonthetable.shadr.us/facebook_connect/connect"

code = "AQAPExNw7MHkxcLTEi5L24iD79pVa-WYxyhBA_bhdWLCM0PCGDuPjh1WqmAyd3_O3_LSjYzPawrinHNP3nv9BCMB_XuTnr8De8xQ2AwXqCaeHUzZUPm2MPyQ_eodOC9-YtjkvXm_PzRX3JG58khalT3AJjVuZvKHn5hWGDSohXLRbHGxW-vOg_Whm3mt_WUkdd0"

result = `curl -F client_id=#{client_id} -F redirect_uri=#{redirect_uri} -F client_secret=#{client_secret} -F code=#{code} https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token`
puts result
```

No matter what I do here, I always get the following error:

```
{"error":{"message":"Error validating verification code.","type":"OAuthException","code":100}}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Tried to self answer, but I don't have enough points.  Here's the snippit that fixed this for me: `redirect_uri = request.url.split('&code=').first`

Answer (score 0):

This does fix it.

```
redirect_uri = request.url.split('&code=').first
```